# Regex expression to split word: first three uppercase letters, then split on uppercase followed by lowercase

Tags: python, regex, string

Is there a regex expression that checks the first three letters of the word and splits it on an uppercase letter only. Afterwards, it splits the remaining part of the word based on uppercase letters followed by lowercase letters.

```
For example,
"FORfirstUpload"

Desired output:
['F','O','R','first','Upload']

I tried using the regex pattern: 
re.findall([A-Z][a-z]*|[A-Z]|[a-z])

But got this output:
['F','O','Rfirst','Upload']
```

Comment: What should be the output for `FfirstUpload`, `firstUpload`, and `FORRfirstUpload`?

Comment: Splitting might probably work with PyPi `regex` and a pattern like `(?<=^[A-Z]{1,2})(?=[A-Z])|(?<=^[A-Z]{1,3})(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?=[A-Z][a-z])`. And if `re` is only considered, something like `(?:^([A-Z])?([A-Z])?([A-Z])?)?([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)` [might help maybe](https://ideone.com/DpZeUs).

Comment: Maybe `^[A-Z]|(?<=^[A-Z])[A-Z]|(?<=^[A-Z]{2})[A-Z]|[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]+`?

Comment: As an alternative to split, you can do this with capturing groups, and a pattern of `(?P<n>[A-Z][a-z]+)|(?P<n>[a-z]+)|(?P<n>[A-Z]+)` - your match collection will have some number of entries, each one having a captured group named 'n' with the text in (so for your example 3 matches, with groups of "FOR", "first" and "Upload")

Comment: @flackoverstow Is that allowed in stdlib's re module? I tried `findall`, `search`, and `match`, and all of them rejected that regex with error `redefinition of group name 'n' as group 2`.

Comment: Ah, maybe not; it's allowed in C# but it gets hard to keep all these languages separate in my head! If you use `(?P<n>([A-Z][a-z]+)|([a-z]+)|([A-Z]+))` then it boils down to the same thing

Comment: Are the first 3 letters always uppercase? Please give more sample input and expected ouput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need three letters, this is a "brute-force" solution that explicitly looks for the first, second, and third uppercase prefix letters. Uses lookbehind `(?<=` and edge-of-word `\b` to find starting letters, assuming your string might not start with the word. If not, you can replace `\b` with `^` to match the beginning of the string.

```
import re
s = 'FORfirstUpload'
re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]|(?<=\b[A-Z])[A-Z]|(?<=\b[A-Z]{2})[A-Z]|[a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]*', s)
# ['F', 'O', 'R', 'first', 'Upload']
```

This could be shorter if Python supported variable-length lookbehind expression, but alas...

---

I would personally not use a single regex for this, but do it in two passes:

```
prefix, rest = re.match(r'\b([A-Z]{,3})(.*)', s).groups()
camel_case_words = re.findall(r'.[a-z]*', rest)
print(list(prefix) + camel_case_words)
# ['F', 'O', 'R', 'first', 'Upload']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd also not aim to do it entirely with regex:

```
import re

input_str = "FORthisIsMyProblem"
pattern = r'(?P<n>([A-Z][a-z]+)|([a-z]+)|([A-Z]+))'

regex = re.compile(pattern)
matches = regex.finditer(input_str)

for match in matches:
    print(match.group('n'))
```

The above will print:

```
FOR
this
Is
My
Problem
```

The first word being broken into chars as a second operation being relatively trivial. This approach can cope with any length of first word, other than 1 upper char (a string like `AthisIsMyProblem` would have a first word of `Athis` )